# How to compile c++ file in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compilation

I am new to Visual Studio and I don't know how to compile a .cpp file. I made just a single .cpp file (ctr + n => Visual C++ => C++ file) and I tried to compile it. But in place where normally there's a compile button (like with c#) there is strange 'Attach' button. I don't get what's going on, but I thought, Visual C++ might be some different version of normal C++. If so is that possible to compile normal C++ file in Visual Studio?

Comment: You must use Visual Studio command line: `cl`

Comment: Or you could create a project around your file to work in the IDE. Please read [Solution and Projects Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b142f8e7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is, Visual Studio don't really know, what to do with your .cpp file. Is it a program? Try the following:

- `File` | `New project`
- `Visual C++` | `Win32` | `Win32 Project`
- Select a name and location for the project
- Next
- Choose `Console application`
- Choose `Empty project`
- Deselect `Precompiled header`
- (optionally) Deselect `SDL checks`
- Finish
- Right-click on `Source files` and choose `Add` | `New Item...`
- Choose `C++ File`
- Choose name for this file
- Write the following inside:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(int argc, char * argv[])
  {
      printf("Hello, world!\n");
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Press F5

Comment: Thank you :). It works now (except it can't include csdtio, but I use iostream and it works with that).

Comment: @Fiodor You seem to use some old version of Visual Studio - 2010 for sure supports `cstdio`. You can use `stdio.h` instead.

Comment: What if you don't want a whole project? What if you just want to run some test code to see how the language works? Does Visual Studio not let you do that?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Sadly, I believe that is a reason why http://ideone.com, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/, http://rextester.com/, etc become popular.

Answer (score 2):

You should, just as you did for C#, create a C++ *project* and add your source file to that. Then there will be all the build options you ever dreamed of.

Comment: I tried that, but it's strange as VS says, that cout is not a member of std and it forces me to add some strange header file stdafx.h.

Comment: @Fiodor did you include the `iostream` header or did you import the `std` namespace?