# How do i automatically clear the terminal in VSCode before execution of script?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am currently using  VS Code to learn Python . So i have to run scripts like 10-15 times a minute , just doing small edits and learning all things. I am running the scripts in integrated terminal of VS code

So apparently the terminal gets horribly cluttered and i have to always clear the terminal manually by running `clear`, I want the terminal to automatically get cleared every time I execute the Python script . Please note that I am not looking for a keyboard shortcut to clear terminal , rather I need the terminal to automatically clear the old output before displaying the output of the present script.
I couldn't find anything that does this , hopefully someone can provide a way out

Comment: This is not a duplicate and I am not satisfied with the accepted answer and all other answers. Why should we have to add extra lines of code for this. There should be a configuration feature builtin with VScode. Clear terminal before each run. Is it too much to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @Jacques answer, you can use the `sys` module to dynamically perform a platform check:

```
import os
import sys

# Linux
if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
    os.system('clear')
# Windows
elif sys.platform.startswith('win32'):
    os.system('cls')
```

Alternatively, see this post on configuring vscode to do this for all programs: [How do I automatically clear VS Code terminal when starting a build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221272/how-do-i-automatically-clear-vs-code-terminal-when-starting-a-build)

Comment: Thanks especially for this one which can clear terminal universally for all programs , will check it out

Comment: You have this the wrong way, linux uses `clear` whereas windows uses `cls`

Answer (score 4):

A simple native vscode solution is to take advantage of a `launch.json` file configurable. Specifically:

`internalConsoleOptions`

> Controls when the internal debug console should open

`redirectOutput`

Both of these used in tandem will open the 'Debug Console' instead of terminal and just provide the necessary output; though it still sends to terminal should you still want it:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
        "redirectOutput": true
    }
]
```

[image: debug console]

Answer (score 2):

You could `import os` and then at the top of your script run `os.system('clear')`

#### Example:

```py
import os
os.system('cls||clear') # this line clears the screen 'cls' = windows 'clear' = unix
# below is my main script
print("hello world!")
```

Comment: Yes working  thanks ,  i am at a very early stage in learning Python so didn't knew it could done using python itself.  I thought i would need to fiddle with some advanced settings in VSCode to achieve it