# How to seperate my program output from the Path being displayed on terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I run a simple python programme, like the following:

```
print("Hello World")
```

The output on the terminal becomes:

```
c:; cd 'c:\Users\super\long\path\here'; & 'c:\Users\super\long\path\here\MyPyENV\Scripts\python.exe' 'c:\Users\super\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.8.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '53164' '--' 'c:\Users\super\long\path\here\Chapter 5\HelloWorld.py' 
 Hello world
```

I have a very small monitor, so there is line wrapping that makes it hard for me to read and worse I sometimes have to scroll down just to see the actual part of my programm, `Hello World`.

Searching around I came across an answer for [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62919341/vscode-how-to-automatically-clear-python-terminal-output-window-before-each-run) question, the solution works as intended:

```
import os
os.system("cls")
print("Hello World")
```

but I also have a slow computer, so now my terminal will first display:

```
c:; cd 'c:\Users\super\long\path\here'; & 'c:\Users\super\long\path\here\MyPyENV\Scripts\python.exe' 'c:\Users\super\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.8.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '53164' '--' 'c:\Users\super\long\path\here\Chapter 5\HelloWorld.py'
```

Then about a second later, clear the screen and only output:

```
 Hello world
```

The waiting time is really not ideal.

Since my terminal is PowerShell, I figured If I included `Clear-Host` in my `launch.json` for my Python debug profile:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "PYrun",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
        // "program": "${file} ; clear-host",       // I also tried this line
            "program": "${file}",  
            "args": ["clear-host"],   
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

But it does not clear the terminal before running the python programm.

Is there a way to simply clear my terminal before running the currently active file via debugging, or in general to make it that the output is separate and clearly discernable from the path?

I am on:

- PowerShelL7
- Windows 11
- Python 3.11

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it is taking noticeable time for `os.system('cls')` to work *but your computer is capable of running Windows 11 at all*, then there is something *seriously* wrong with the computer - this is not a programming question and tehre are not other meaningful ways to solve the problem. You cannot "simply" clear the terminal from within Python because *the terminal is being created by a completely separate program*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel His question boils down to how he can make the terminal output discernable. That is totally a programming question. And whether his computer is slow or not has no bearing on that, he is just asking for a solution that would work on a slow computer.

Comment: @KovyJacob I didn't say that 'how to clear the terminal' isn't a programming question. But *avoiding the slowness* isn't a programming question, because the cause of the slowness is outside of anything to do with programming. The on-topic part of the question is how to do it at all, and that's a duplicate.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The questions above are about VScode, and many of the answers are VScode specific.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Those questions are asked regarding VScode, and most of the answers are Vscode specific (key shortcuts to clear the terminal, settings to change).

Comment: Yes, but *so is this one*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Oh, you're right. I missed that in the paths he displayed. My bad.

Comment: You can use print("") to print a blank line, so maybe have it print a whole bunch of blank lines before printing 'Hello World'.