# How to clear terminal in Visual Studio Code just before running code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have been coding for about a year as a hobby and I code mainly on Pycharm. I started to use Visual Studio Code because a course required using it. Every time I run my program it leaves everything from previous run into terminal and this slows me down since I have more trouble finding out what the actual print or error message was. Pycharm always cleared the previous run from terminal. If I remember correctly I am using some sort of education version of Visual Studio Code.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508562/14694631) is basically what I was looking for, but I can't find "Code-runner: Clear Previous Output" in my settings even with search terms.

Comment: This was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713604/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: @Musaab That is similar, but not quite what I was looking for. In your suggested answer terminal is cleared with keyboard shortuct. I am looking for a feature that clears terminal everytime I click run button and only after clearing it shows the terminal output.

Answer (score 3):

Go to settings and type Terminal.
You are looking for:
Debug > Terminal: Clear Before Reusing.

Tick the box and every time you will run your script, the terminal will clear itself from previous output. No need for extensions, just standard VS Code settings.

Comment: This seems to work only when I run in debug mode. This seems to have a drawback that it slows the proses down. Not much, but otherwise the code I run runs instantly, in debug mode it takes two secconds, even when running only one print statement.

Comment: Don't know what it could be. Mine is working fine whether I will debug or not terminal will still get cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Turn to extension marketplace, make sure you have installed and **enabled** Code Runner.

Then add the following configurations in **Settings.json**:
[image]

```
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
```

Run Code, the result will be dispalyed in **OUTPUT**. If you don't want execution scripts, you can achieve it by adding

```
"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false
```

Detailed information please view [Configuration](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner#configuration).

Comment: Where should I look for Settings.json?

Comment: **Manage-->Settings**, then click the logo in the top right corner to `Open Settings(JSON)`. I upload the screenshot in my answer, please check.@Heikki

Comment: It seems to work at first, but after some testing it seems it will not always print errors. For example in python I typed `print(")`, witch gave me no error. Even `raise Error` gave me no error for some reason. Sometimes it would give me correct errors, but it was inconsistent when it gave them.

Comment: @Heikki. It will happen sometimes when using code runner. it's recommended that you use java extension to run java code.