# How to compile C++ code on windows using msvc compiler?

Tags: visual-c++

I am using a remote machine and have to compile a cpp code. I have msvc compiler for windows. How can I compile my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile c++ file in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684190/how-to-compile-c-file-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to compile using the `command prompt`, not the `IDE`.

Theses steps were found in the [Documentation of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019).

---

First you need to open the properly command prompt:

- Option 1: Open the application **Developer Command Prompt for VS**, or
- Option 2: Open the application **Visual C++ 2015 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt**

Then on the prompt send the command `cd C:\path\to\file.cpp` (write the correctly path)

> Compile the file with `cl /EHsc file.cpp`

---

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019